# C input of char returns a different char

Tags: c

I am learning C and I've stumbled upon a really weird problem. When I input a single char, it returns 1-2 different chars. I don't really get why it returns the different chars instead of the original. could someone please explain me why it doesn't work?

the goal of this code is to accept 4 char inputs and return the input given.

code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

 char c;

 c = getchar();
 getchar();
 c = c + "/0";
 printf("%c\n", c);

 c = getchar();
 getchar();
 c = c + "/0";
 printf("%c\n", c);

 c = getchar();
 getchar();
 c = c + "/0";
 printf("%c\n", c);

 c = getchar();
 getchar();
 c = c + "/0";
 printf("%c\n", c);

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you expect `c=c + "/0";` to do? I am sure it does not what you want it do. `c + "/0"` adds the number in c to the char pointer pointing to the start of "/0". With c=0 the result points to "/0", with c=1 the results points to "0", with c=2 the result points to "", with c>2 it is undefined behavior.

Comment: Your char c is a single char, you need a char array char c[2]

Comment: @WernerHenze, I tried to end my char input there, so that no ghost input was stored afterwards

Comment: Compile with warnings enabled (`-Wall`) and fix any issues pointed out by the compiler.

Comment: Why are four different values printed and not the same (incorrect) one each time? Because the four apparently identical strings `"/0"` are each stored in a different place in memory. The arithmetic adds the least significant byte of this address to your character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C, characters and strings have different data types: a character is an integer (typically 8-bits long with value from -128 to 128), and a string is an array of characters (either a C-style string where the end of the string is represented by a null character `\0`, or some other form of array).

### Characters

If you want to store a character in a variable of type `char` you could use any of the following:

```
char c = 'c';        //< Set c to the character 'c'
char c; c = 'h';     //< Set c to the character 'h'
char c = '\65';      //< Set c to the character 'A' (see ASCII codes)
char c = getchar();  //< Store a character from a function returning char
char c = 10;         //< Not always considered good practice (but still valid)
```

### Strings

If you want a C-style string in C you could use:

```
char szMyString[] = "This is my string"; //< Array of 18 characters
char szAnotherString[5] = "asdf";        //< Array of 5 characters
char szBuf[5];  sprintf(szBuf, "hi");    //< Array len: 5, String len: 2
char szBuf[128]; scanf("%s", szBuf);     //< Ask the user for a string
char szBuf[5]; szBuf[0] = 'a'; szBuf[1] = '\0';  //< String with length 1
char szBuf[5]; szBuf[0] = 'a';    //< Not a string (just an array of type char)
```

It is important to note that characters are written in C using the single quotes `'` and strings using the double quotes `"`.  In other languages (like Python) you can use double or single quotes mostly interchangeably but in C there is a difference.

### Joining Strings

If you want to join two strings you need to make sure you have enough space to contain both strings.  You can join two strings by adding the second to the end of the first or copy both original strings into a new array.

```
// Append to the first string
char szFirst[128] = "The first string...";
char szSecond[] = "and the second string.";
strcat(szFirst, szSecond);

// Copy strings into new array
char szJoined[128];
char szFirst[] = "Hello";
char szSecond[] = "World";
sprintf(szJoined, "%s %s", szFirst, szSecond);
```

### Mixing strings and characters

If you want to add a character to the end of a string you need replace the null character at the end of the string with your new character and add a new null character following your string.  You should first check your target string has enough space to hold the new character.

```
// By hand
char c = 'A';
char szString[128] = "The capital of a is ";
nOldLength = length(szString);
szString[nOldLength] = c;
szString[nOldLength+1] = '\0';

// Using sprintf
char c = 'H';
char szString[] = "ello";
char szOutput[128];
sprintf(szOutput, "%c%s", c, szString);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to store multiple chars in a single char variable, that doesnt work. your `char c` stores a numerical value from either 0 to 255 (unsigned) or -127 to +128 (signed). If you want a string, one thats properly terminated, you have to change your code:

```
int main(void) {

 char c[2];

 c[0] = getchar();
 getchar();
 c[1] = '\0';
 printf("%s\n", c);

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Md.SumsuddinShojib I didn't downvote your answer, and I removed my comment once I found it was incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal  is to accept 4 char inputs and print the input given, then just remove `c = c + "/0";` from you code. It should work

Answer (score 0):

A `char` represents only one character. It does not make sense to add/concatenate a `char` (here `c`) with a `string` (here `"\n"`).

In C a string is delimited with `"`. A char is delimited with `'`.

If you want to do arithmetic with `char`s you both operands need to be `char`s.

You want to return the original input `char` and therefore simply remove

```
c = c + "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to end the input. If you are reading one `char`, then you can directly output it.

```
printf("%c\n", c);  // Note: %c prints one char
```

If you want to build a string from that char, then you need a terminating null byte.

```
char c[2];
c[0] = getchar();
c[1] = '\0';
printf("%s\n", c);  // Note: %s prints a string (chars until terminating null byte)
```

Answer (score 0):

first

The null character is `'\0'`, not `'/0'`.

second

```
 c = c + "/0";
```

In C as above you can not append strings.

---

For printing it you do not need to convert it in array and use `printf`

for printing character you just need

```
printf("%c\n", c);
```

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement, there is no need of lines containing:

Also, you are using one more `getchar()` which is not needed.

Remove these lines:

```
getchar();    // This is not needed.
c = c + "/0"; // This is not needed.
```

So the working code would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

 char c;

 c = getchar();
 printf("%c\n", c);

 c = getchar();
 printf("%c\n", c);

 c = getchar();
 printf("%c\n", c);

 c = getchar();
 printf("%c\n", c);

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: If *the goal of this code is to accept 4 char inputs and return the input given* then you should remove the extra `getchar` calls too.

Comment: Oh yes. I didn't notice that! @ilent2 thanks. will update :)

Comment: Perhaps a single `scanf` might be better then (if there are whitespace character inbetween)?

Comment: The reason for the second `getchar` is to clean off the `newline`. Without them, the program ends after only 2 inputs.